# How to transform a button into this styled button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a button looks like I want. I managed to do this, but the problem is that requested me to use **javascript for posting form**, this is breaking completely accessibility for this website.

So, I would like to know how can I obtain the same effect by using `<input type"submit" />` while keeping the *mouse hover* effect on all the button, not text only (my first solution had this problem).

Here is how should look the button (you can also see mouse over effect):

[image: Button styled with mouseover effect]

Here you can find a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FireDragonDoL/hjC7P/

And here is code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="nothing">
      <div class="button"><span><span>Leggi tutto</span></span></div><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="button"><span><span>Leggi tutto</span></span></div><br /><br />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    outline:none;
    border:0;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
a {
    color:#750e0e;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a.reverse-color {
    color: #D6D6B0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container .button {
    background: url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/762638/Stackoverflow/ButtonStyled/bkg_btn_hover.png") no-repeat scroll 1px 0 transparent;
}
.container .button span {
    background: url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/762638/Stackoverflow/ButtonStyled/bkg_btn_hover.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 0 transparent;
}
.button {
    background: url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/762638/Stackoverflow/ButtonStyled/bkg_btn_rosso.png") no-repeat scroll 1px 0 transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    width: auto;
    float:right
}
.button span {
    background: url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/762638/Stackoverflow/ButtonStyled/bkg_btn_rosso.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 0 transparent;
    color: #750E0E;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px #D7E9A4 !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #FFFFFF;
}
.button:hover span {
    color:#333;
}
.button span span {
    line-height: 52px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}
.button:hover {
    background: url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/762638/Stackoverflow/ButtonStyled/bkg_btn_hover.png") no-repeat scroll 1px 0 transparent;
}
.button:hover span {
    background: url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/762638/Stackoverflow/ButtonStyled/bkg_btn_hover.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 0 transparent;
}
.container, .nothing {
  clear: both;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:10px 0;
}
```

The only idea I have is actually using a big image of the button background, (a wider, possibly), and use `<input type="image" />`, but in that case I don't know how to place text over the image.

Any suggestion appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, there isn't a way to do this through a single html element. Maybe with `:before` and `:after` something can be done, or with `position: relative` too.

At the moment, I'll stick with javascript code to transform those items into "submit" buttons.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible but problem with different browser. Simple way is include your text with image. and use the sprite technique to the hover effect.

Comment: I thought it was only a fault by myself missing enough skills in css... I can stick with javascript however, if that's the case. But I don't want place the text **in** the image because I've a lot of buttons.

Comment: ok. you can do this but you have write some extra code, because all browser positions are not same. if you want to some feature detection for IE browser then here is very nice website link : http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: Yea I'm going to work with it, still I have no idea on how to achieve this result through css and a single input tag.

Comment: I didn't find any other way, looks like this is the only way I know at the moment.